# Как записать анимацию в unity во время режима игры

Tags: unity3d, анимация, vr

Я хочу записать анимационный клип в play mode, то есть объект на сцене будет двигаться и всё изменения будут записываться в клип, движение преимущественно будут реализовываться с помощью vr шлема, что-то типа mocap, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я хочу используя шлем виртуальной реальности в режиме игры записывать анимационные клипы, то есть также как если бы я НЕ в режиме игры менял компоненты типа transform, только всё это происходит в режиме игры, а положение объекта я меняю с помощью vr оборудована, что то типа moution capture.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, тебе надо записывать всё, что происходит на сцене. Все позиции, все изменения, тебе нужно записывать в таймлайн. С этим, тебе поможет видео от Brackeys:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqlHpPzS22U

Далее, в "режиме записи клипа" ты просто записываешь видео с экрана (через unity естественно): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqW-Fg5VafQ

На самом деле, это сложная задача. Тут много чего надо думать.